# Can we add a user to user chat function on Stack overflow? What could be advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**[EDITED For live example ]**

Now I want to chat with THE FLAGGER, so I can interactively understand what the problem is, so I can make question better or delete it!

**[EDITED after receiving POSSIBLE duplicate flag]**

Using same page of answer makes it perfectly clear that 'chat' is matching, but the purpose is not.

**[EDITED after testing existing chat feature ]**

**What I found?**

- We can create a chat room ('create new chat room' button) I am not able to see. My reputation is 41)
- Chat room is not 1-on-1. It's open.
- Only we have to reject incoming request to make it private.

**What's difference?**
- Invite to a 1-on-1 chat by clicking the user profile image on the same page of the answer
- Chat by the side of answer

- Don't shift to create a chat room ->invite -> accept -> copy paste question -> chat
- Chat will end in 10 min or after clicking end chat.

**[EDIT: After watching how current Stack Exchange chat works find a link in the comment section:]**

I imagine:

[answer page -> [invite chat over question] -> [chat on same page like a live stream YouTube]]]

(Post more comments so I will able to make it more clear.)

I don't want to make Stack Exchange a chatting website, but we **can** we add a chat system for sake of interactive problem solving in questioner and answerer **USER TO USER**?

By putting limits to assure that chat is not a "chat":

1. Adding a reputation points restriction.
2. Adding time windows for interactive answering.
3. Adding request to accept

---

I also want to hear what could be its side-effects?

---

But on the brighter side we will have more interactive community in the sense of problem solving.

---

Where it could be useful:

1. For contributor and **repairing questions:**

   Some of people over Stack Exchange face a hard time getting out of vague questions, or simplifying it. Here if the answerer or questioner accept to chat and get the IMMEDIATE more interactive effort to make question make sense it will be great!

   (What do you think?)
2. Many times people have some small problems in code provided by an answerer which cannot be solved over comments section and can be more interactively solved over chat.

Comment: [Status-completed?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) How is this different from the existing site chat? You even have the 20 rep required to chat.

Comment: USER to USER   feature

Comment: And you (general you, not specific you, and at a certain rep) can create a brand new room and invite another user to a 1 on 1 chat. Still not seeing how this is any different than the existing chat feature.

Comment: Ok wait i am adding

Comment: Stack Overflow was designed to *not* be a typical back-and-forth forum, but rather a strict question and answer site.

Comment: @akashraigade you don't seem to be listening. **This already exists**.

Comment: I suspect our existing feature does not suit this questioner because it requires both users to be active on the same question at the same time (in order to follow the chat link). Maybe the questioner wants to be able to "summon" an arbitrary user to their chat. In that case, the consensus is that *we don't want that*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You can "summon".  When you invite a user to chat they get a inbox notification

Comment: @Nathan, I wasn't aware of that. Hopefully it's not too much trouble. I wonder how many of those "invites" Jon Skeet receives in a day.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Not sure.  There was an issue not too long ago where a low rep user was spamming chat request but that can be dealt with via a mod flag.  From what I have seen it is not really an issue at present.  Might also have to do with the fact that not many people actually know how to invite users to a chat room.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi there's restrictions placed on that such as both users must have 20 rep and the person being "notified" has been in chat recently.

Comment: khmm... wait a min i just put an massage on that , its probaly not gonna work  i am imagining [answer page ->[invite chat over question]->[chat on same page like a live stream youtube] ]

Comment: Yeah... Good idea posting a link that everyone's going to click to see :-)

Comment: IRead  and react on new edits

Comment: But...... all in all, this is STILL just the same functionality as chat. Yes, you access it differently and it behaves slightly different, but it's chat. the easy answer there is : even if you are making improvements over what we have, it's not worth re-doing a feature that works....  And one clarification: This community isn't there for "interactive problem solving". It's actually not even technically there for "problem solving", so much as it's there for "knowledge gathering"

Comment: Please [edit] this question to look as if it was written in one go by somebody with some idea of how formatting works. If people want to see how it developed, they can look at the revision history.

Comment: If you have a problem with an answer post a comment to it. an answer should not be a gateway to tech support

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow [already has a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I think i should BOLD **user to user**

Comment: @akashraigade The chat *is* for users chatting with users.  It's not like the chat exists for users to chat with anyone else (although I guess there are a few bots here or there).

Comment: @akashraigade You can set up user to user chats with the chat system. In fact there are times where the system does that for you.